# How to navigate to a controller action in javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a button in a page and `onlick` I'm calling:

```
var viewUser = function (e) {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "UsersManage")' + '/' + e.row.data.Id;
}
```

I have the following controller:

```
[Area("Admin")]
[Route("Users/Manage")]
public class UsersManageController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{key}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string key)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I would like that the url would be `/Admin/Users/Manage/useridhere`.

But when I click on the button I get an error 400 and the url is `/Admin/UsersManage/useridhere`.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I changed the Javascript function:

```
var viewUser = function (e) {
    window.location.href = '/Admin/Users/Manage/' + e.row.data.Id;
}
```

But I still can't reach the action. How exactly do I need to name my controller, action and view?

Comment: Use window.location.href for the relative path that u use.

Comment: You wrote `"UsersManage"` in the argument for `Url.Action()`, why do you expect something else than `/UsersManage/`?

Comment: Because UsersMange is the controller name.

Comment: Because you set **[Route("Users/Manage")]**.

Comment: window.location.href = url;

Comment: Are you able to reach your controller by entering `localhost:port/Admin/Users/Manage/userid` in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try url `/Users/Manage/useridhere`

[image]

We have  `[Route("Users/Manage")]` so we shouldn't use the controller name. And the `[Area("Admin")]` doesn't affect the route if we use the default route in `Program.cs`, the `Area` attribute only asks the view to reach `/Areas/Admin/Views/Chart/Index.cshtml` path.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` is the key here;

```
var viewUser = function (e) {
    window.location.href = '/Admin/Users/Manage/' + e.row.data.Id;
}
```